# Can the Excel VBA Range.Find method be used to find multiple values?

Tags: excel, pandas, vba

I'm attempting to search for text located in an Excel spreadsheet.  I was looking at the examples for the Range.Find method located in Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find.

These examples only show how to search for one value.  Is it possible to search for more than one value using the Range.Find method or would one have to place multiple Range.Find methods inside a nested For loop or some other VBA structure? Or would it be more efficient to use a Pandas structure?  I'd like some expert advice on how to implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, for example, looking for the values "unopened", "needs work" and "incomplete" located in separate cells in the spreadsheet.

Comment: You can use 3 `Find` calls, one for each value. If they need to be adjacent and there's multiple instances of values, then you might need to loop.

Comment: The `Range.Find` method is the VBA version of the Excel Find (and Replace) functionality. You can do everything in VBA that you in Excel, not more, not less. To search for multiple values, you will have to issue multiple Range.Find-commands.

Comment: Create a common proc to Find For example `Private Sub FindText(txt as String)` Simply pass the string to it. This way you will not have to copy and paste the `.Find` code 3 times...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do repeated `Range.Find` calls and use the `After` argument to make sure the next call doesn't re-find the previous range. VBA actually has a built in function to help simplify this proces, [Range.FindNext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext)

So you first set up a `Range.Find` and then VBA saves the arguments so you can do `Range.FindNext` and it will duplicate your arguments from the `.Find` Function. You only need to specify the `After` argument in `Range.FindNext`.

Here is an example and a function for how to set this up:

```vb
Sub Example2()
    Dim relevantRanges(2) As Range
    Set relevantRanges(0) = FindAll("unopened")
    Set relevantRanges(1) = FindAll("needs work")
    Set relevantRanges(2) = FindAll("incomplete")
    'Now each element in relevantRanges contains a range of all found cells with it's word
End Sub

Function FindAll( _
                    LookFor As String, _
                    Optional WithinSheet As Worksheet = Nothing, _
                    Optional LookIn As XlFindLookIn = xlValues, _
                    Optional LookAt As XlLookAt = xlPart, _
                    Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False _
                ) As Range
    
    If WithinSheet Is Nothing Then Set WithinSheet = ActiveSheet
    
    With WithinSheet.Cells
        Dim rFirst As Range
        Set rFirst = .Find(What:=LookFor, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, MatchCase:=MatchCase)
                
        If rFirst Is Nothing Then
            Set FindAll = Nothing
            Exit Function
        End If

        Dim FoundRange As Range
        Set FoundRange = rFirst
        
        Dim rNext As Range
        Set rNext = .FindNext(After:=rFirst)
        
        While rNext.Address <> rFirst.Address
            Set FoundRange = Union(FoundRange, rNext)
            Set rNext = .FindNext(After:=rNext)
        Wend
    End With
    
    Set FindAll = FoundRange
End Function
```

The reason I use `rFirst` and `rNext` as separate ranges is so I have an exit condition for the loop. I can compare the addresses to make sure that when `.Find` returns back to the first match, it exits the `While` loop.

Comment: Cool.  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I just realised I didn't add anything to handle the case where `rFirst Is Nothing`. Which would occur if the search text doesn't exist. Please check the revised code.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks @Toddleson.

Comment: Exquisit, helpful & instructive. @Toddleson

Comment: Elegantly, straightforwardly and cleanly written.  Good job @Toddleson.  Thanks for helping me out.  I'm looping through each of the 'relevantRanges( ) objects and copying and pasting the cells into the sheet 14 cols at a time, then pasting to a new row 2 rows below so the new data can be seen on one sheet when printed.