# Get specific item in a range

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code:

```
    Debug.Print "Full range: " & searchResult.Address
    Debug.Print "Size of range: " & searchResult.Count
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In searchResult
        Debug.Print "from for each: " & cell.Address
    Next cell
    Debug.Print "from item 0: " & searchResult.item(0).Address
    Debug.Print "from item 1: " & searchResult.item(1).Address
    Debug.Print "from item 2: " & searchResult.item(2).Address
```

This is my output:

```
Full range: $M$125,$M$148,$M$161
Size of range: 3
from for each: $M$125
from for each: $M$148
from for each: $M$161
from item 0: $M$124
from item 1: $M$125
from item 2: $M$126
```

The for each is giving me the result I want, while the "item" give just the next item within the worksheet, not into that range.
I just want to get the address of a specific item in that range. Let's say something like "searchResult(2).address = $M$161" (in case it's 0-based) like you would access items in an array.
I'm sure it's very simple but can't find what's the name of the property I need to use...
Thanks for your help.

Comment: A discontinuous range does not return a continuous array! Such a range has areas. You ca n see its specific area address in `searchResult.Address`, like comma separated...

Comment: For reference : [Range.Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.item)

Comment: @FaneDuru, ok thanks for this information. Thanks to your comment using "searchResult.Areas.item(1).Address" did the job, thanks !

Comment: If you want to use an index into the search results then maybe you need something like a Collection of cells instead of a Union'ed Range object.  Where/how are you creating `searchResult` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams the searchresult is created somehow like in this answer / function. It's just a list of cell addresses where the search string was found. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69901221/can-the-excel-vba-range-find-method-be-used-to-find-multiple-values/69902042#69902042

Comment: You could modify that function to return a Collection of cells which you could then loop over using either For Each or a counter

Answer (score 1):

A discontinuous range does not return a continuous array...

In order to convert it in a 1D array (values and addresses), please try the next function. It iterates between all the range areas and all cells of each area:

```
Function DiscRangeToArray(rng As Range) As Variant
   Dim A As Range, c As Range, arrVal, arrAddress, i As Long
   ReDim arrVal(rng.cells.count - 1): ReDim arrAddress(rng.cells.count - 1)
   For Each A In rng.Areas
        For Each c In A.cells
            arrVal(i) = c.value: arrAddress(i) = c.Address: i = i + 1
        Next c
    Next A
    DiscRangeToArray = Array(arrVal, arrAddress)
End Function
```

You can test it using the next testing `Sub`:

```
Sub testDiscRangeToArray()
   Dim rng As Range, jgArr
   Set rng = Range("$M$125,$M$148,$M$161")
   jgArr = DiscRangeToArray(rng)
   Debug.Print Join(jgArr(0), "|")
   Debug.Print Join(jgArr(1), "|")
   
   'For a range not having only one cell in an area:
   Set rng = Range("A2:A3,B4,C5:D6")
   jgArr = DiscRangeToArray(rng)
   Debug.Print Join(jgArr(0), "|")
   Debug.Print Join(jgArr(1), "|")
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to FaneDuru's comment I could find the solution. Doing:

```
searchResult.Areas.item(1).Address
```

Did the job in my case.

Comment: You should know that this way works only for your specific case. Sometimes, an area may have more cells. In that case, your code should iterate between each area cells. It only happens that it returns correctly for your specific range..

Comment: So what do you propose ? Storing the addresses in a string array?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you really want accomplishing. You can place all the cells belonging to a discontinuous range in an array, indeed. Of course, if this is what you want. I can show you a function doing that. In fact, i will post a function returning a jagged array containing the cells value and their address, too.